# ¿ Qué lenguaje de programación es?

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, visual

¿alguien me podría indicar de qué lenguaje de programación se trata, o cómo podría identificarlo mediante la sintaxis?

Me llegaron a comentar que tal vez se trate de un tipo de visual antiguo, pero no me han dado más detalles.

```
Sub voucherExtraPrinting()

var vteEncapsulado: N1
Var vteImprimir : N1

vteEncapsulado = 0

    For i = 1 To 8
        For j = 1 To vteContador
            If (Trim(gbliExtraVoucher[i]) <> "") AND (Trim(vteMetodoPago[j]) = Trim(gbliExtraVoucher[i]))
                total = vteMonto[j]
                If (vteEncapsulado = 0)
                    
                    
                    Format Linea As " ",Trim(vteFecha){<20},Trim(vteTiempo){>20}
                    Call GenericPrint(FALSE, FALSE, gbliPrintEDIOnLocalPrinter, Linea)          
                
                EndIf
                
                
                Format Linea As @Dwon,"|",Trim(vteMetodoPago[j]){<30}, " $ ", Trim(total){<6},"|"
                Call GenericPrint(FALSE, FALSE, gbliPrintEDIOnLocalPrinter, Linea)  
                
                vteEncapsulado = vteEncapsulado + 1
            EndIf
        EndFor
    EndFor
    
    If (vteEncapsulado <> 0)
        Format Linea As @Dwon,"----------------------------------------"
        Call GenericPrint(FALSE, FALSE, gbliPrintEDIOnLocalPrinter, Linea)
                
        If(Not gbliPrintEDIOnLocalPrinter)
            Call CutPaperTMT88(4)
        EndIf
    EndIf


    For j = 1 To vteContador
        vteMetodoPago[j] = ""
        vteMonto[j]      = ""
    EndFor
EndSub
```

Comment: `Visual Basic` diría yo, la ultima vez que toque eso fue hace como 6 años.

Comment: Que versión estimas que sería ?

Comment: Te pasaron solo ese fragmento de código o tienes un proyecto completo en tu pc?

Comment: Vaya... no veia visual basic desde la prepa, yo le voy a que es una version superior a la 6 porque no recuerdo haber visto codigo con arrobas

Answer (score 3):

Si tienes visual studio code, haz un archivo nuevo y pega el código en el panel de abajo te mostrará el lenguaje de programacion que estás escibiendo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]